# Tables with the same name in the same DB (very strange bug)

Tags: mysql, azure

Have you ever seen something similar to this (picture)?

[image: Multiple appearances of the same table]

A table appears multiple times!!

I don't know exactly how this began.
Whenever I make a change (alter) to a table, a new instance appears

I've used 2 different clients (**HeidiSQL, DBeaver**)
and my web applications work without problems.

Any ideas

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the result [of a known bug on Azure for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/322028/duplicate-tables-being-created-in-azure-mysql-data.html). A fix was deployed last month, but you'll need to [restart your server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-restart-server-portal) before it takes effect. After restarting, you will see the correct table information.